# PHPExcel chart using logarithmic scale

Tags: charts, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

Using PHPExcel 1.8.1 to create a chart. However I am not able to find the option to enable logarithmic scaling on said chart. These are the axis properties I have found apigen.juzna.cz/doc/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/source-class-PHPExcel_Chart_Axis.html#175, but don't seem to address what I am looking for:

`$xAxisStyle =  new PHPExcel_Chart_Axis();
$xAxisStyle->setAxisOptionsProperties('low', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);`

This is the chart that is created:
[Typical line chart, with with ranges too great to display all points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mffqp.png)

After chart is created, I then enable logarithmic scale on the axis to display it properly:
[Edited line chart so all lines are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xaiI.png)

Can PHPExcel perform logarithmic scaling and I am missing it or is there some other type of work-around?

Comment: I have this problem too, do you find a solution ?

Thank you !

Comment: Sorry, I did not find a solution. I ended up breaking the graphs into smaller pieces so the data would be displayed correctly.

Comment: No matter thank you for your answer !